# plot(x,y) with strptime doesn't work with singular data point

Tags: r, plot, time, shiny

I am trying to plot a scatterplot in shiny, using times of day on the y axis.
When plotting multiple points, the y axis looks great.

[image: sample plot]

Here's the code:

```
     output$outputPlot <- renderPlot({
        coords <- subset(coords, location == input$cities)
        month <- coords$month
        time <- strptime(coords$format_time, format = "%l:%M:%S %p")
        plot(month, time)
      })
```

But when there's only 1 data point in `coords`, the plot's time scale on the y-axis isn't in terms of time anymore, and the data point appears in the middle of the graph.

[image: sample plot 2]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read and include features from [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269), especially the part about reproducing and pasting your data. The dataset is not available for us to demonstrate with; think of using a smaller example that can be included in your question.  For example, does the problem occur with just a normal (non-Shiny) graph?  If so, present that simplified example instead.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is that R doesn't know how to guess an appropriate range for a single point. Typically it expands the range of data by 4% of the range (look at [`?par`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.0/topics/par) and look for `'xaxs'`), but with a single point that means nothing.

So we need to tell it what `ylim` to use. (Similarly, your x-axis needs some guidance, too.)

Fake data:

```r
set.seed(2)
coords <- data.frame(tm = Sys.time() + runif(20, -3e7, 3e7))
coords$month <- as.integer(format(coords$tm, format = "%m"))
coords$format_time <- format(coords$tm, format = "%l:%M:%S %p")
head(coords)
#                    tm month format_time
# 1 2018-10-24 20:15:17    10  8:15:17 PM
# 2 2019-10-19 05:07:04    10  5:07:04 AM
# 3 2019-07-21 14:19:22     7  2:19:22 PM
# 4 2018-10-13 03:44:57    10  3:44:57 AM
# 5 2020-04-03 21:32:22     4  9:32:22 PM
# 6 2020-04-03 15:27:59     4  3:27:59 PM
```

The "normal" plot looks fine:

```r
month <- coords$month
time <- strptime(coords$format_time, format = "%l:%M:%S %p")
plot(month, time)
```

[image: many points, good y-axis]

but the single-point does not:

```r
sub <- coords[1,]
month <- sub$month
time <- strptime(sub$format_time, format = "%l:%M:%S %p")
plot(month, time)
```

[image: single point, wrong y-axis]

So we fix it by specifying the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments. In this case, since I'm inferring it is meant to be a year of months (x) and a day of times (y), I can hard-code them, but in other situations you might want to just substract/add a small amount from the one datum you have:

```r
sub <- coords[1,]
month <- sub$month
time <- strptime(sub$format_time, format = "%l:%M:%S %p")
xlim <- c(1, 12)
ylim <- strptime(c("12:00:00 AM", "11:59:59 PM"), format = "%l:%M:%S %p")
plot(month, time, xlim = xlim, ylim = as.numeric(ylim))
```

[image: one point, corrected axes]

You only need to specify `ylim` to answer this question, but without setting `xlim=` here, the previous x-axis spanned 6-14, not good for months. Also of note is that I had to coerce `ylim` to numeric for the plot, it did not work with `ylim` in its pure `POSIXt` form ... not sure exactly why that is the case, but this doesn't detract from the utility of the plot in general.